# How to include empty string in string_agg?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I've done a [groklearning exercise](https://groklearning.com/course/intro-sql-1/) up until the point of:

> Make sure to list all properties, even if there is some unknown
>   address information; replace any missing parts with an empty string

Could someone guide me on how to make this work?

```
SELECT D.council_name, string_agg( P.house_number || ' ' || P.street  || ' ' ||    L.locality,  ', ' ORDER BY S.contract_date) AS commercial_properties
FROM Sales S, Properties P, Districts D, Localities L
WHERE S.property_id = P.property_id
AND P.locality_id = L.locality_id
AND P.district_code = D.district_code
AND P.primary_purpose = 'COMMERCIAL'
AND S.contract_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'

GROUP BY D.council_name;
```

But it prints:

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  council_name   |                                 commercial_properties                                  |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| COOTAMUNDRA     | 218 PARKER ST COOTAMUNDRA                                                              |
| COWRA           | 6 VAUX ST COWRA                                                                        |
| GREAT LAKES     | 102 MANNING ST TUNCURRY                                                                |
| LAKE MACQUARIE  | 214 MACQUARIE RD WARNERS BAY, 19 NELSON RD CARDIFF, 21 NELSON RD CARDIFF               |
| NEWCASTLE       | 8 RURAL DR SANDGATE                                                                    |
| PARRAMATTA      | 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 ROSS ST PARRAMATTA |
| PORT STEPHENS   | 17 STOCKTON ST NELSON BAY                                                              |
| THE HILLS SHIRE | 24 LEXINGTON DR BELLA VISTA                                                            |
| WYONG           | 172 PACIFIC HWY TUGGERAH, 20 AMSTERDAM CCT WYONG                                       |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Instead of:

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  council_name   |                                 commercial_properties                                  |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| COOTAMUNDRA     | 218 PARKER ST COOTAMUNDRA                                                              |
| COWRA           | 6 VAUX ST COWRA                                                                        |
| GREAT LAKES     | 102 MANNING ST TUNCURRY, MACWOOD RD SMITHS LAKE                                        |
| LAKE MACQUARIE  | 214 MACQUARIE RD WARNERS BAY, 19 NELSON RD CARDIFF, 21 NELSON RD CARDIFF               |
| NEWCASTLE       | 8 RURAL DR SANDGATE                                                                    |
| PARRAMATTA      | 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 AIRD ST PARRAMATTA, 5 ROSS ST PARRAMATTA |
| PORT STEPHENS   | 17 STOCKTON ST NELSON BAY                                                              |
| THE HILLS SHIRE | 24 LEXINGTON DR BELLA VISTA                                                            |
| WYONG           | 172 PACIFIC HWY TUGGERAH, 20 AMSTERDAM CCT WYONG                                       |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It doesn't print "MACWOOD RD SMITHS LAKE" as it is missing the `house_number`.  How can I add the missing parts to the results?

Comment: Please *always* disclose your RDBMS and version. "Being sorry" does not help, [edit] the question, that helps.

Comment: In addition to @ErwinBrandstetter 's comment, please see [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Please provide a fiddle from one of the choices in that post (not rextester)! Also, we need to know your RDBMS - there are many subtle differences between servers!

Comment: [tag:sql] is *not* the same as [tag:sql-server].  Please clarify your platform by tagging it with [tag: sql-server] if that *is* your platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use COALESCE to map null to an empty string for all attributes that may contain null:

```
string_agg( COALESCE(P.house_number, '') 
         || ' ' 
         || COALESCE(P.street, '')  
         ...
) AS commercial_properties
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `DEFAULT` constraint for `string_agg`. It avoids storing the value field as `NULL`.

Comment: You might want to add an example on how the original poster of the question can achieve this, as OP does seem to be a beginner. As it stands your answer is only partially helpful.